# Excel: Use cell or row only once

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a list of 1000's of unique identifiers (locations), each with a value attached. EG:

- LOCATION_A  10
- LOCATION_B  3
- LOCATION_C  6
- LOCATION_D  12
- LOCATION_E  6
- etc

I want to create a rule whereby once a value for a location has been used, that location can no longer be used in further calculations.

At the moment I use VLOOKUP to return the values. I suppose I could instead create a calculation row by row (for each location), but with thousands to get through this doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Is OK for you tu use VBA? Because with only Excel this is not possibile. If you just want to use Excel functions you can use IF and COUNTIF function to apply VLOOKUP whith only those rows that you find one times (which is similar to your question but not the same).

Comment: What do you mean by "once a value for a location has been used, that location can no longer be used in further calculations". Can you please add your desired output here